# How to declare a std::chrono::duration<double> variable in c++

Tags: c++, list, time, c++-chrono

I am working on a code where I am calculating the duration of time and then saving it in list.

```
auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
/*
 *some code here
*/
auto finish_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

std::chrono::duration<double> time_duration = finish_time - start_time ;
```

Now here I need to save `time_duration` in a list at a given index. If that given index, already contains a value, I need to add `time_duration` with the current value of that index and save it. For this I have below list and code:

```
list <std::chrono::duration<double>> dTimeList;

auto iter = dTimeList.begin();
advance(iter, 0);  
*iter+= time_duration; //Error at this line
```

But running above code I get below error:

[image]

Most probably this error is coming because I have empty list with no items in it. This is why I thought of adding a item at 0th index like below:

```
auto itr = dTimeList.begin();
advance(itr, 0);
std::chrono::duration<double> t = 0.0;
dTimeList.insert(itr, t);
```

but again above is also giving below error. How can I resolve this issue. Thanks

`No suitable constructor available to convert double to std::chrono::duration<double>`

Comment: The error you get when trying to advance the iterator when it's at `end()` is, as you've figured out, clear. You never tell us what goes wrong with the second try though. Make a [mcve].

Comment: Use `list.push_back(t)` to add items to list, don't use `advance(itr, 0)`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have edited the question.

Comment: @user2807083 I need to save at particular index in list so cannot use `list.push_back(t)`

Comment: There is no suitable constructor available to convert `double` to `std::chrono<double>`.  However you _can_ use _explicit_ construction:  `std::chrono::duration<double> t{0.0};`.

Comment: @SAndrew A `list` is unsuitable if you want indexing. (They are in fact unsuitable for most things and are rarely observed in the wild.) Use `std::vector` or `std::deque`.

Comment: @molbdnilo If you want to save at a particular index, you might want to use `std::map` instead.

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri That could also be a good idea, in particular if the sequence can have "holes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you should not use list to store data at index. Try to use `std::unordered_map` instead.

```
#include <unordered_map>
auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
/*
 *some code here
*/
auto finish_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<double> time_duration = finish_time - start_time ;

typedef int YourObjectIdType;

std::unordered_map<YourObjectIdType, std::chrono::duration<double>> dTimes;
```

and now insert or update item like this:

```
dTimes[objectId] += time_duration;
```

or like this:

```
 auto it = dTimes.find(objectId);
 if (it != dTimes.end()) {
      *it += time_duration;
 } else {
      dTimes.insert(std::make_pair(objectId, time_duration));
 }
```

also, you can use `std::map` the same way, it slightly slower, but [`begin()`, `end()`) range is sorted.

Comment: Thanks for this example. Can you tell me what does this means `typedef int YourObjectIdType;`

Comment: As I see in your previous question, you have some object id of unknown (to me) type, you can use that object_id as key of correspondent type in `std::unordered_map` or in `std::map`. `typedef` is not necessary needed. I just assume that type is `int`.

Comment: Either you can use `int` or `std::size_t` index as key for that maps

Comment: Upvoted, but consider using `dTimes.emplace(objectId, time_duration);` instead of `dTimes.insert(std::make_pair(...`

Comment: I see no logic of storing by index 0,1,2,3 ... N, and not using vector? Do we know what is the app logic here?  It might be std::vector would be sufficient.

Comment: Have you compiled and run the above?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to write to the end iterator. When the list is empty, `dTimeList.begin() ==  dTimeList.end()`, so you can't write to it.

You need to check if the index exists first, and extend the list otherwise:

```
void add_time_to_list(
    std::list<std::chrono::duration<double>>& l,
    const std::chrono::duration<double>& t,
    std::size_t index = 0
) {
    if (index < l.size()) {
        *std::next(l.begin(), index) += t;
    } else if (index == l.size()) {
        // New element; add to back
        l.push_back(t);
    } else {
        // Here you can throw an error that index is too big
        // or append 0 until it gets to the desired size or something
    }
}
```

Note that accessing arbitrary indexes like this could mean that you don't want a `std::list`. This would be easier with a `std::vector` (`*std::next(l.begin(), index)` becomes `l[index]`). I would also suggest a `std::map`, where the function can just be written as:

```
void add_time_to_list(
    std::map<std::size_t, std::chrono::duration<double>>& m,
    const std::chrono::duration<double>& t,
    std::size_t index = 0
) {
    m[index] += t;  // if m[index] doesn't exist, it is default constructed. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> No suitable constructor available to convert double to std::chrono::duration

I dare to suggest dealing with std::list is far from a core issue here.

Dealing with `std::chrono`, one should know the foundation concepts of it. For what is not explained here please look it up on cppreference.com

Step one. You decide which Clock you need/want to use.

```
using Clock = typename std::chrono::high_resolution_clock ;
```

Step two. You use the duration nested type, declared in it. In your use-case you would like to have a sequence of durations.

```
using time_durations_sequence_type = std::vector<Clock::duration> ;
```

type naming is very important. I deliberately use the generic term 'sequence'. You might push the idea of std::list to implement it, but I fail to see why. Thus I am using `std::vector` above.

Also notice, I do not use `double` or `long int` as the "duration" type. Firstly  `std::duration` is a "time taken for event to happen". Second, it is not a scalar it is a class type. Traditionaly, from C years, time concept was based just on ticks.

So, to cut the long story short we use the std::duration concept , concretized as a nested type in the "clock" we have selected to use here.

```
   // not a point in time
   Clock::duration
   //
   // there is no guarantee above 
   // is the same type as
   // std::chrono::duration<double>
   // and we do not need one
```

And above is all we need to proceed to implement the functionality you require.

```
     // two points in time
     auto start_time = Clock::now();
     auto finish_time = Clock::now();

      // the duration
      Clock::duration time_duration = finish_time - start_time ;
```

Now we store the duration in our sequence type.

```
      time_durations_sequence_type tdst{ time_duration } ;
```

And elsewhere we use the sequence of stored durations we have accumulated.

```
//  time_durations_sequence_type tdst
for (auto duration : tdst ) {
        std::cout << std::endl 
           << duration.count() << " nano seconds" 
           << std::endl;
}
```

Notice how above we used the `count()` method to get to the actual ticks, which by std::chrono default, do represent nanoseconds.

Working code is [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CuLsyIHrAddG6tBV) .